# Cosa sapreste dirmi della diffusione del verbo "sfanagliare" nelle diverse regioni italiane?

Tags: word-choice

Come credo sia conosciuto da tutti quelli che usano viaggiare con l'automobile, molti italiani hanno uno strano rapporto con gli abbaglianti; alcuni li amano così tanto che preferiscono mantenerli sempre accesi, altri invece li usano per segnalare, se non addirittura per comunicare informazioni di vario genere, dalla presenza di autovelox alla protesta per presunte violazioni del codice della strada.

Al di lá delle considerazioni e dei commenti circa queste abitudini, mi piacerebbe sapere se il verbo "sfanagliare" è normalmente usato, e compreso, in tutte le regioni italiane o se, magari, ci sono altri verbi in uso, purchè simpatici come quello.

Laddove qualcuno non avesse compreso l'uso del aforementioned verbo, ecco un esempio:

> "Ehi!" - dice il marito a sua moglie - "Quello li mi sta sfanagliando, st***o!"
>
> E la moglie, "Caro, rallenta; magari più avanti c'è un autovelox, cribbio!"

Comment: A Roma, non pervenuto.

Comment: A Napoli nemmeno è pervenuto.

Comment: @Kyriakos, not related to the question, but I noted that you asked many questions and you haven't accepted any answer yet. Not a critique, but it's a good practice on StackExchange to mark one answer as accepted if you think it answered your question properly. See: http://italian.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @Gabriele, I'm sure I will accept some answers in the next future, but I think it is better to wait for the time being; after all, we still are in private beta.

Comment: @Kyriakos sure thing. I just noticed the fact and it wasn't clear to me whether it was a voluntary choice or just inexperience with the SE network. Thanks for clarifying. It's indeed a legitimate choice and you can accept whenever you feel like to ;)

Comment: I've heard "sfaragliare" in and around Milan.

Answer (score 8):

Il verbo ***sfanagliare*** è un verbo inventato, non esistente nella lingua italiana, ma questo penso fosse chiaro dalla domanda.

Personalmente non l'ho mai sentito usare nel nord Italia, quindi non credo abbia una diffusione regionale omogenea. Un'alternativa che mi è capitato invece di sentire  è ***sfanalare***, con significato identico.

Ad ogni modo, non sono sicuro dell'interpretazione di ***sfanalare***/***sfanagliare*** con il significato di ***accecare con gli abbaglianti***. Probabilmente il significato che gli attribuirei è lo stesso di ***fare i fari***, ossia ***segnalare qualcosa tramite i fari abbaglianti***, solitamente accendendoli e spegnedoli ripetutamente. Per esempio

> Non mi ero accorto che il semaforo fosse diventato verde e il tizio dietro mi ha fatto i fari

(ok l'esempio è un po' tirato, sappiamo benissimo che il tizio di turno normalmente suona il clacson e tira una bestemmia...)

oppure

> Una vecchia consuetudine italiana era quella di sfanalare per segnalare la presenza della polizia stradale

Nell'esempio che hai menzionato userei invece qualcosa del tipo

> Quello lì mi sta abbagliando (con sti c***o di fari, *ndt*), st***o!

or

> Quello lì mi sta accecando (con sti c***o di fari, *ndt*), st***o!

Comment: The practice of *sfanalare* is quite common in people driving (over the speed limit, of course) on the leftmost lane of highways.

Comment: Yep, those are people asking the others to make them pass, and don't keep the leftmost lane busy. When they do it, I just stay where I am. `:)`

Comment: Thus forcing people to overtake from the right. In highways, left lanes have a minimum speed limit, but in all roads the rule is to use the first free lane from the right. In Italy not observing this is punished with a fine up to 168€ and 4 points from the license. Closing the off-topic, I've seen the term `mi sfanalano` in the graphic novel "S." by Gipi, a comic book artist from Pisa.